# how to debug gollum issue with mathjax

Tags: mathjax, gollum-wiki

Can anyone outline steps to resolve issue with gollum not rendering math?

I am running gollum with --mathjax but it doesn't produce desired outcome.
My version of gollum is 5.2.1.

I am trying to render this file: https://github.com/mojombo/gollum-demo/blob/master/Math.pod